# How do I create new variables based on the size of a List?

Tags: java

I have a `List` with say size *n*, and I have to dynamically create `n` variables ie i want to dynamically create the variables depending upon the size of the list. How can i achieve this?

Say i have `List` as `List<Integer> year` with *n* elements in it;

then i have to create the *n* `Integer` variables from the above list.

EDIT : If i have list with 3 elements in it the i want to create 3 variables like

```
a = list(0);
b = list(1);
c = list(2);
```

like this the list may have any number of elements then i have to create those many variables. Hope I am clear now.

thanks.

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive title.

Comment: Just create another list of the same size with the new variables in it? Or do I completely miss the point? The question is so vague and the initial answer is too straightforward that it's pretty confusing.

Comment: Why do you want to create variables? Can't you just access the data directly from the list?

Answer (score 7):

You can not create `n` local variables as you seem to suggest. (What would their names be?)

You need to store the variables (or rather integer values) in a `List` or some other `Collection`, and populate them within a loop:

```
int n = year.size();
List<Integer> theIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    theIntegers.add(i);
```

gives you `year.size()` number of integers (0, 1, 2, ...).

You can then access the integers through

```
theIntegers.get(4);
```

if you want to read the integer with index 4. and

```
theIntegers.set(4, 10);
```

if you want to update the integer with index 4, to the value 10.

---

You could in this case also create an array:

```
int[] ints = new int[year.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++)
    ints[i] = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I know of in Java to dynamically add variables to a scope. You can use a map as a type of variable... well, mapping instead:

```
final List<Integer> years = getYearList();
final Map<String, Integer> yearMapping = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(int year : years)
{
    final String name = generateNameForYear(year);
    yearMapping.add(name, new Integer(year));
}

// Later... Get "variables" out of the map:
final String variableName = "fooYear";
if (yearMapping.containsKey(variableName))
{
    final Integer variableValue = yearMapping.get(variableName);
}
else
{
    // "variable" does not exist.
}
```

Comment: you can't have primitives as type argument in java. Needs to be a class, such as Integer.